# Is it insecure to use hardcoded strings for xml elements?

Tags: android, textview, adt, hardcoded

When I use this hardcoded strings for my TextView elements, ADT warns me:

> Hardcoded string "Text", should use @string resource

So is it insecure or something that ADT warns me not to use this way?

Comment: What are "elements"? Do you mean XML elements? What are "hardcoded names for elements"? What is the complete and precise message that you are getting, and what is the specific element it is complaining about?

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: Yes I mean XML elements

Comment: I guess he is asking about the attribute values, e.g. `text="someHardCodedString"`

Comment: I edited my question and added the warning I'm getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice as it makes your app less configurable, but it's not unsafe.

In the folder res/values/strings.xml you should declare the string you are using for better practice.

Here's a guide on how to do this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 1):

All xml files in your app will be compiled and after that, they are no longer readable for human. So using hardcoded strings is totally safe, it's only a bad practice.